# How do I let my program print a complete right angle triangle for certain values?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, triangle-count

[image]

I tested the program out with 88 and it was left with one star to complete the triangle. 87, two stars 86 three stars. This went on for certain numbers.

These are the two options for programming `generate` function

• One is to compute the length of the last line, say `maxLen`, and use a double for-loop to generate a line of one star, a line of two stars, a line of three starts, and so on, ending with a line of `maxLen` stars. The value of maxLen is the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to the
larger solution of the quadratic equation `x ( x + 1 ) = 2 * num.`

• The other is to use one for-loop to print num stars while executing `System.out.println()`wherever the newline is needed. The point at which the newline is needed can be computed using two accompanying integer variables, say `len` and `count`. Here the former is the length of the line being generated and the `count` is the number of stars yet to be printed in the line. We start by setting the value of 1 to both integer variables. At each round of the iteration, we decrease the value of `count`, if the value of count becomes 0, we insert the newline, increase the value of `len` and then copy of the value of `len` to `count`. **When the loop terminates, if the value of `count` is neither equal to 0 nor equal to count, we extend the present line by adding more stars.**

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class TriangleSingle
    {
        public static void generate(int x) //Generates the Triangle
        {
        int len, count;
        len = 1;
        count = 1;
        for (int k = 1; k <= x; k++)
        {
                System.out.print("*");

                count --;

                if (count == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    len ++;
                    count = len;
                }



        }

        if (count!= 0 || count != len)
                {

            System.out.println("*"); //Completes the triangle if needed
                                       // This is the **problem spot**
                }
```

Comment: You need two nested loops. Outer loop for rows. Inner loop for stars on a row. Count stars printed. Exit outer loop if total printed stars >= requested stars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:-   

  public static void generate(int x) //Generates the Triangle
            {
            int len, count;
            len = 1;
            count = 1;
            for (int k = 1; k <= x; k++)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println();


            }

            }
```

Comment: It worked but we were giving particular instructions. Let me add them

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to increment the count `c` of printed stars in the inner loop, which prints each row, but check it against the desired number `n` in the outer loop, which determines how many rows to print. This way we're sure to print complete rows, but we stop as soon as we've printed at least `n` stars.

```
public static void generate(int n)
{
  for(int c=0, i=0; c<n; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++, c++)
      System.out.print('*');
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that this might work but for a new user in Java, which the OP clearly is, I don't think that you should be using for-loops with multiple statements in each part like you did with the int c = 0, i = 0. Also, this can definitely be done with less than 4 variable and better named ones. Please edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out !!!

```
public class pyramid {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Length of pyramid : ");
    int length = s.nextInt();

    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*\t");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution but I just added the particular instructions we were given

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
public static void generate(int x) //Generates the Triangle
{
    int len, count;
    len = 1;
    count = 1;
    for (int k = 1; k <= x;)
    {
        System.out.print("*");

        count --;

        if (count == 0)
        {
            System.out.println();
            len ++;
            k++;
            count = len;
        }
}
```